# Python 2.7 syntax error when importing module

Tags: python, debugging, syntax-error, spyder

Thanks for reading this question first of all.

I am trying to import a module into a new script.

I am using the following command:

```
import mosaic.qdfTrajIO as qdf
```

This returns the following syntax error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/reneb/projects/mosaic/mosaic/utilities/mosaicLogging.py',
wdir='C:/Users/reneb/projects/mosaic/mosaic/utilities')


File "C:/Users/reneb/projects/mosaic/mosaic/utilities/mosaicLogging.py", line 50
class mosaicLogging(object, metaclass=metaSingleton):
                                     ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This is the code from line 42 through 59:

```
class MessageFormatter(logging.Formatter):
def format(self, record):
    try:
        record.msg = record.msg.strip()
    except:
        pass
    return super(MessageFormatter, self).format(record)

class mosaicLogging(object, metaclass=metaSingleton): #this is where the error takes place

"""A custom logging class that uses the Python logging facility. Logs are automatically saved to a metaMDIO instance,
    and to a file log when DeveloperMode is active.
"""

_loggers = {}

log=logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: `metaclass=metaSingleton` is Python 3 syntax. Do you really have to run the outdated and no longer supported Python 2? End-of-life for Python 2 was set over 10 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yeah i found that out just now too. Its weird to me as the website this software is from tell em that the software is written for python 2.7 but the code appears to only work in python 3.